# Can I share a 220v circuit between an AC compressor and baseboard heat?

Tags: hvac, 240v, compressor

I will be adding a 220v baseboard heat as a supplement to an addition.  The addition also has a smaller AC compressor with 20amp 240v, the same spec as the heater.

I wonder if I should share this circuit between the compressor and the heating element considering they will never be run at the same time.   ...how do I find out if code requires a dedicated circuit to the compressor?

I do have room in my panel, it would just be very hard to add another "home run" for the new baseboard heating element.

~Todd

Answer (score 1):

The NEC allows one or the other to be used for calculated values, I have installed both on the same circuit but with larger electric heat there may be 2/ 3 circuits required. With both being smaller choose the larger for the over current protection and you should be fine depending on your county and state local requirements.

Comment: Thanks Ed   I had a local contractor confirm this as well.   The only concern was that the AC and heat may compete, but they are different zones, so there's no way this could happen.